# How to hide Spring Security OAuth2 endpoints from Swagger UI?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2, swagger-ui

I have an API application built with Spring Boot. I used **swagger-springmvc** v0.9.5 plugin along with Swagger UI to generate a live documentation and interaction front-end to the API methods.

I recently introduced Spring security and OAuth to the application. This introduced a few more sections appearing in the Swagger UI for:

- **authorization-endpoint** which has a bunch of HTTP operations available under the `/oauth/authorize` path
- **check-token-endpoint** which has a bunch of HTTP operations available under the `/oauth/check_token` path
- **whitelabel-approval-endpoint** which has a bunch of HTTP operations available under the `/oauth/confirm_access` path
- **whitelabel-error-endpoint** which has a bunch of HTTP operations available under the `/oauth/error` path

I can understand what they are for, but I do not want them to appear in my Swagger UI front-end. How do I hide them?

com.mangofactory.swagger.plugin.SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin's configuration does offer includePatterns() method but no way to exclude patterns. With includePatterns() every time some one adds a method to the API, will need to remember to add it there, which is not ideal. I don't have a common prefix for all API methods that I can use includePatterns() with either.

Comment: I know this is a year old, but why not just prefix all methods with /api/, and then you can use `.includePatterns("/api/.*")`

Comment: As I said in the question itself : I don't have a common prefix for all API methods that I can use includePatterns() with either.

Comment: Yeah, I was just suggesting as a work around to force all the methods to have a common prefix, and to use some generic prefix (i.e. /api/ for them all). But I can understand if that is not feasible if the api's are already in use

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to accept all paths excluding `/oauth.*`

```
.select()
.paths(input ->
    !PathSelectors.regex("/oauth.*").apply(input) &&
    PathSelectors.any().apply(input))
.build()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I resolved it by altering the Docket creation parameters.
I was using

```
@Bean
public Docket oAuthService() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/")
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class,
                    String.class)
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
            .alternateTypeRules(
                    newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                            typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
                            typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,
                    newArrayList(new ResponseMessageBuilder()
                            .code(500)
                            .message("500 message")
                            .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error"))
                            .build()))
            .securitySchemes(newArrayList(apiKey()))
            .securityContexts(newArrayList(securityContext()))
            .enableUrlTemplating(true)
            .tags(new Tag("Oauth Service", "Oauth Service"));
}
```

Which resulted in all the spring-oauth endpoints being part of my swagger spec.
I changed the apis registered to use my basePackage instead of any().
Something like this:

```
.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.base.package.name"))
```